# How do you run arithmetic on values in one column based on the values of a different column and group by a third?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
time            measure_name    measure_value::bigint
12/1/2021 0:00  volume          791
12/1/2021 0:00  successVolume   791
12/1/2021 0:01  volume          1261
12/1/2021 0:01  successVolume   1261
12/1/2021 0:02  volume          1332
12/1/2021 0:02  successVolume   1332
12/1/2021 0:03  volume          1145
12/1/2021 0:03  successVolume   1145
```

What I'd like to do is get the success rate **by time**:
(successVolume/volume)*100

```
time            successRate
12/1/2021 0:00  100.0
12/1/2021 0:01  100.0
```

I've searched through many posts but haven't quite found one that helped.  I'm sure I'm just not searching using the correct question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join both values from two subselects

But you should save dates in MySQL only in the tiome format that MySQL uses yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss

Also you should add a index on (time,measure_name )

> ```
> SELECT a.`time`, (a.`measure_value` / b.`measure_value`) * 100 as successRate
> FROM
> (SELECT `time`, `measure_name`, `measure_value` FROM timemeasure WHERE  `measure_name` = 'volume' ) a
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `time`, `measure_name`, `measure_value` FROM timemeasure  WHERE `measure_name` = 'successVolume' ) b
> ON a.`time` = b.`time`
> ```
>
> ```
> time           | successRate
> :------------- | ----------:
> 12/1/2021 0:00 |    100.0000
> 12/1/2021 0:01 |    100.0000
> 12/1/2021 0:02 |    100.0000
> 12/1/2021 0:03 |    100.0000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97b651eac2e8b1bf1b684a6c8b25d4e8)*

Comment: Thanks a ton.   This worked perfectly.  I didn't consider joining on sub selects.

I agree with time format.  Unfortunately I am not in control of the data in this case.  This is a database table populated from a python restapi call to Splunk for use in a different visualization tool.

Thanks again!